# How to vertically and horizontally center an img in a fullscreen div?

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

The following code shows a logo and it's background. I can't get the logo centered vertically. Is it because the background div has no height defined? How can I get the background to be always 100% of the screen size with a centered logo?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/3/">
</div>
```

Comment: Set a fixed width on the logo. eg: width: 300px;

Comment: Position the logo absolutely as well, then see the Related links -->

Answer (score 2):

Using `absolute` `position` for image, positing to center of `div` using `top` and `left` and them move it back for half using `transform:translate`

There is code

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
#header {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;   /*positing top left corner of image to center*/
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* move left and up for 1/2 of image */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/3/">
</div>
```

There is [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uqmnhbt1/) with `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/abstract/3/">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vertical center using this method inside your `.logo` class. But you most define your **parent** height for it to be effective.

```css
.logo {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; /* Added Code */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Added Code */
    }
```